# Neo4j - Accessing Neo4j web UI from my local machine which is running on server

Tags: neo4j

What are the additional properties we need to set to access the neo4j Web UI which is running on server from the local instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `conf/neo4j-server.properties` to allow the webserver to accept connections from IPs other than localhost:

```
# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

You can then access the remote Neo4j Browser at `http://REMOTE_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS:7474`